# How to access test accounts created by TestRPC from a Solidity test with Truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc, testing

With Javascript tests, it is possible to access the accounts which TestRPC creates using:

```
contract('MetaCoin', function(accounts) {
   // tests here can access accounts[n] to get the public keys
}
```

But how can I use those addresses from a test written in Solidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to make a suggestion.

In the `TestMetaCoin.sol` example, you can see that the contract owner address is used. (See `tx.origin`)  Therefore, I see no reason why you couldn't hard-code other account addresses in a Solidity library file and then import the library into your test.  You might be then be able to use `$ testrpc --account="<privatekey>,balance" [--account="<privatekey>,balance"]` to ensure that the addresses in your library are re-used each time you launch.

You can do some fairly complicated things with Solidity tests. (See http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/testing-for-throws-in-solidity-tests) However, judging by the truffle docs, I get the impression that they may not be  designed for your use case.

http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/solidity-tests

Comment: That's reasonable. As I'm making progress with developing in Solidity, I'm realising that maybe `.sol` tests serve a different purpose than `.js` ones. Use solidity to test complex internal logic and JavaScript for testing contracts.

Comment: I'd say that's about right.  I've heard the argument made that the `.js` tests are essentially integration tests by virtue of their dependency on `web3`.  While that may be true, they can be used to test complex internal contract logic just as well as a Solidity test might do.  The advantages of Solidity tests are rapid development, they focus on the contract logic itself (as you say) and they require less overhead.